# Support for Kendo-Angular-UI and Kendo-Angular-Develop

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

We are considering integrating Kendo-Angular-UI and using its components. How well supported is Kendo-Angular-UI?

There is a lot of functionality present in Kendo-Angular-UI-Develop, that is not present in Kendo-Angular-UI. While the road-map discusses the plan for introducing newer components, it does not mention if/when newly added functionality for existing components will be available and supported. Does anyone know where I can find this information?

For example, the "collapseChanged" event for a SplitterPane component is only shown as a part of Kendo-Angular-UI-Develop. When will this be available as a part of Kendo-Angular-UI?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, but this might help. 
The recent Telerik webinar talked about this a bit (IDK how helpful it will be to you). Here's a link to the webinar: https://www.telerik.com/campaigns/kendo-ui/wb-feb-2018-release-r1

I also found this roadmap: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am following/using Kendo UI for Angular from the very beginning. And I use Kendo UI for several years (for jQuery before and for Angular now). There is [official release page](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/) and there is [development page](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/) as you already figure it out.

Everything you see in development page will sooner or later be released on release page. From my experience this means from a few days to maybe a week, 2 weeks on rare occasion. You can get version from development with `-dev` on npm.
Details about your specific example are [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1273).

Road-map is just a helper for developers when we can expect first official release for components mentioned in roadmap. But pre-releases are available much sooner on developement portal.

So in short, development is pre-release, and all features in most cases are officially released in a matter of days.

Comment: Thank you! The changes I mentioned are now already available as a part of the latest stable release (which is surprising considering that the change was implemented less than a couple of weeks ago)! Pretty impressive so far.

Comment: Yes, there work is amazing. If feature request is small and logically(would add additional value for all customers) they implement it fast. For larger changes or feature request they point you to [Feedback portal](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback). Community can vote on features they are interested. Roadmap is updated based on feedback portal. The only downside/complain you will get from Telerik customers are that they/we wish that new components (to match Kendo UI for jQuery) would be implemented faster.